# Wordpress will not load, any of it

Tags: wordpress

The following, besides basic html struct tags, is all I see when using inspector on the bas domain... not what Im missing??

```
?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Comment: It seems that your server is not configured to run PHP code.

Comment: agreed... Im just going to burn it down and start over. TY for the response!!

Comment: Your also missing the opening php `<`